# Upgrading fundamental ngx is breaking the UI

Tags: angular, sap-fiori

I am recently trying to upgrade `fundamental-ngx` library - `@fundamental-ngx/core` from `0.32.0` and `0.36.0`. Once that was done all the existing UI is broken. The colors and the basic fiori styles are removed. I tried to inspect the components but the CSS variables that are used do not have any values set. I also installed `fundamental-styles`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, previously there was a default value associated with the variables that you mentioned. but looks like they have removed it. Now you have to import the css based on the styles. You can try to do the following and see if it helps:

```
ng add @fundamental-ngx/core
```

This will ask for a theme and based on selection automatically update angular.json and styles.scss with fonts and styles.